# Copyright issue for uploading books to Mendeley

Tags: publications, copyright

I wonder whether importing a pdf file of a book that I downloaded in my Mendeley library is illegal or not.

Any advice?

Comment: With whom are you sharing the book on Mendeley? Did you buy the book or download it via you library or some ither source?

Comment: I don't understand your distinction between "importing" and "downloading". Can you clarify the question a bit? Moreover, the question itself says "uploading". I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I understand like this: They downloaded a book somewhere and now imports it into their Mendeley library.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog, would that make it public? Is it a form of "publishing"? Or would it just make it more usable to the one who does it - the library "owner"?

Comment: @Buffy That's exactly what I'm asking in my first commend. Mendeley allows all of it, afaik.